# Openstack-Ocata dashboard Error: Unable to update default quotas for Cinder

Tags: openstack, cinder

when I updated the default quotas,some errors on dashboard.

Error: Unable to update default quotas for Cinder.

Comment: Please describe more on the steps what you took.

Comment: can you post the apache log here? This error message is too vague to debug.